# Why isn't the factorial function defined for non-integers, but the gamma function is?

Tags: number-theory

You cannot calculate n! when n is a non-integer, but you can calculate Γ(n+1) for non-integers when n! = Γ(n+1). Why?

Comment: In the context in which that is true, $n!$ is a function defined at nonnegative integer arguments and $\Gamma(n+1)$ is defined on the entire complex plane minus its poles.

Comment: (+1)Good question.I think it is just a game of definitions.Say, what is so important about multiplying numbers from 1 to n?

Comment: $\Gamma(n+1)$ is equal to $n!$ only when $n$ is a non-negative integer. You may evaluate $\Gamma(x)$ for non-integral $x$, but $x!$ won't be defined. The Gamma function can be thought of as the "extension" of the factorial function (see Wikipedia page for Gamma function)

Comment: For alternative (possible) definitions see this [link](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/hadamard/HadamardsGammaFunction.html).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni The link you provided was intellectually amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Glad you liked it @euclid !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral form of the [**Gamma function**](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2#E1) is given as follows with the real part of $z>-1$.
$$
\displaystyle \Gamma (z+1)=\int_0^{\infty } e^{-t} t^z \, dt
$$
Integration by parts yields the fundamental recursive equation.

$
u=t^z,\ \ \ du=z t^{z-1}dt,\ \ \ dv=e^{-t}dt,\ \ \ v=-e^{-t}
$

$
\Gamma (z+1)=\int _0^{\infty }e^{-t}t^zdt=\left(\lim_{t\to \infty } \, - t^ze^{-t}-\lim_{t\to 0} \, - t^ze^{-t}\right)+\int _0^{\infty }e^{-t} \left(z t^{z-1}\right)dt
$

$
\Gamma (z+1)=\int _0^{\infty }e^{-t}t^zdt=0+z\int _0^{\infty }e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt=z\Gamma (z)
$

$
\Gamma (z+1)=z\Gamma (z)
$

This equation looks just like the factorial function. Let $z$ equal a natural number $n$.

$
\Gamma (n+1)=n \Gamma (n)=n(n-1) \Gamma (n-1)=n(n-1) (n-2) \ldots 3*2*1*\Gamma (1)
$

Now we need to calculate $\text{$\Gamma $(1)}$.

$
\Gamma (0+1)=\int_0^{\infty } e^{-t} t^0 \, dt=\int_0^{\infty } e^{-t} \, dt=\lim_{t\to \infty } \, -e^{-t}-\lim_{t\to 0} \, -e^{-t}=1
$

$
\Gamma (1)=1
$

In conclusion, the identity is established.

$
\Gamma (n+1)=n \Gamma (n)=n(n-1) \Gamma (n-1)=n(n-1) (n-2) \ldots  3*2*1*1=n!
$
$$
\displaystyle \Gamma (n+1)=n!
$$

Comment: beautifully explained!

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand how the gamma function is been *analytically continued* and $n!$ (or its gamma equivalent) is not.

The continuation is a literature standard and see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation#Applications